# Get minimum time on same date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an attendance table like this in MySQL

> EmpID | EventTime
>
> 90010 | 2014-03-05 06:50:30
>
> 90010 | 2014-03-05 06:50:45
>
> 90010 | 2014-03-05 06:51:02
>
> 90020 | 2014-03-05 06:52:50
>
> 90030 | 2014-03-05 06:55:47

The employee with ID '90010' is submitted more than 1 attendance data on March 5th.
Now, i want to make a report of attendance on March 5th, but when i run my sql it always give 3 record for ID '90010'.
This is my query

```
SELECT b.EmpID, a.EventTime
FROM MST_Attendance a, MST_Employee b
WHERE a.EmpID=b.EmpID
AND DATE(a.EventTime)='2014-03-05'
```

That query give a result exactly the same as the table content. Actually, i need a result like this:

> 90010 | 2014-03-05 06:50:30
>
> 90020 | 2014-03-05 06:52:50
>
> 90030 | 2014-03-05 06:55:47

Please anyone help me about the query i've to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your query, assuming you already have foreign keys on your MST_Attendance table, you can just do a query on that table, since you have the two columns EmpID and EventTime there. You need to group by EmpID to obtain the minimum time:

```
SELECT EmpID, MIN(EventTime) as attendancetime
FROM MST_Attendance
WHERE DATE(EventTime)='2014-03-05'
GROUP BY EmpID
```

If you need to combine other details of employees, assuming all your EmpIDs are unique in your MST_Employee table, you can use an alias and nest the query above, followed by a RIGHT JOIN:

```
SELECT a.*, b.attendancetime 
FROM MST_Employee a
RIGHT JOIN (
SELECT EmpID, MIN(EventTime) as attendancetime
    FROM MST_Attendance
    WHERE DATE(EventTime)='2014-03-05'
    GROUP BY EmpID
) b 
ON a.EmpID = b.EmpID
```

Comment: It works, but when i want to show all attendance data on march (1st - 31st) of 1 employee (e.g : '90010') it give just 1 result (the minimum time)

Comment: I'm sorry i'ts solved. I just have to group it by DATE(EventTime). Thanx

Answer (score 1):

using `MIN` of EventTiem with `GROUP BY` will help you get the desired result

```
SELECT b.EmpID, MIN(a.EventTime) AS EventTime
FROM MST_Attendance a, MST_Employee b
WHERE a.EmpID=b.EmpID
AND DATE(a.EventTime)='2014-03-05'
GROUP BY b.EmpID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.EmpID, MIN(a.EventTime)  minEventTime
FROM MST_Attendance a, MST_Employee b
WHERE a.EmpID=b.EmpID
AND DATE(a.EventTime)='2014-03-05'
GROUP BY b.EmpID
```